# Удалить название узла, оставив вложенные элементы в HTML

Tags: c#, html, xpath

Необходимо почистить HTML файлы от лишних узлов, при этом оставить вложенные узлы. Пример фрагмента такого HTML ниже:

```
<tr>
<td>
  первая строка
  <p>текст</p>
  <span>1. <span><b>первый</b> элемент списка</span></span>
  <span>2. <span><b>второй</b> элемент списка</span></span>
  Последняя строка
</td>
</tr>
```

Необходимо получить что-то вроде:

```
<tr>
<td>
  первая строка
  текст
  1. <b>первый</b> элемент списка
  2. <b>второй</b> элемент списка
  Последняя строка
</td>
</tr>
```

Т.е. удалить все `span` во всем документа и удалить все `p` внутри `td`

Пытался следующим образом:

Сначала получаю всех родителей элементов у которых есть `span` путем xPath: `//span/..`

После перебираю дочерние узлы у полученного узла.
Собираю информацию в виде текста:

- Если дочерний узел является `span`, то я сохраняю его `InnerHTML`
- Иначе я сохраняю `OuterHTML`

После такого прохода по всем дочерним элементам, я удаляю у родительского узла все дочерние элементы и в качестве `InnerHTML` присваиваю сохраненные ранее данные. Однако это проблему не полностью решает, остаются `span`, предположительно, если один `span` был вложен в другой.

Может быть есть более логичный способ удаления? Не хотелось бы решать проблему через замену текста через регулярные выражения...

Пробовал еще подобный вариант, это нахождение первого родителя, после этого удаления всех дочерних элементов описанным выше способом, после этого поиск снова первого родителя по тем же условиям... И так до тех пор пока ничего не найдется. Однако данный способ очень долгий, хотя и вычищает все идеально.

Comment: Вы всё правильно сделали, когда решили воспользоваться xpath. Разобраться с имеющейся проблемой Вам поможет рекурсия - обходите элементы документа рекурсивно, избавляясь от ненужных элементов. Желаю успехов.

Comment: @Geslot, а чем именно правильное решение? Гораздо проще и быстрее было сделать string.Replace, чем подключать тяжеловесный парсер HTML. Стоит учитывать время, потраченное на изучение работы с парсером. Как правило самое продуктивное решение - в лоб, именно через замену текста.

Comment: Ведь вы слышали выражение "Все гениальное - просто!". Зачем усложнять?

Comment: @Geslot, А что подразумевается под рекурсией? Ведь выборка по xPath выдаст полный линейный список всех вхождений.

Comment: @z668, не получится обычным string.Replace сделать. Во-первых, у тегов могут быть атрибуты, потому уже придется делать через регулярное выражение, во-вторых, как удалить только те узлы, которые находятся в определенном? Как я в вопросе выше писал, нужно удалить только узлы <p> которые расположены в узле <td>, при этом не нужно узлы <p> удалять в других местах (в <body>, <div> и т.д.)

Comment: _"подключать тяжеловесный парсер HTML"_ -- отдельный html-парсер и не нужен, т.к. можно использовать существующий в Windows html-парсер, который состоит из нескольких COM-объектов -- они же используются в IE. и WebBrowser фактически работает с теми же COM-объектами.

Answer (score 2):

> Необходимо почистить HTML файлы от лишних узлов, при этом оставить вложенные узлы.

метод Html.CleanupAsync позволяет очистить html с помощью кода на javascript.
очистка происходит в WebBrowser (его можно использовать и в консольных программах).
для удаления тегов используется функция removeNode().
ниже пример и реализация метода Html.CleanupAsync.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Html {
    public static Task<string> CleanupAsync(string innerHtml, string js) {
        var ts = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        var t = new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
            var html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
                  <html><head><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
                  </head><body>" + innerHtml + "</body></html>";
            var wb = new WebBrowser() { DocumentText = html };
            wb.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) => {
                wb.Document.InvokeScript("eval",
                    new object[] { "(function() {" + js + "}())" });
                ts.SetResult(wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
            };
            while (!ts.Task.IsCompleted) Application.DoEvents();
        });
        t.TrySetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        return ts.Task;
    }
}
```

---

```
var html = @"<table><tr><td>
  первая строка
  <p>текст</p>
  <span>1. <span><b>первый</b> элемент списка</span></span>
  <span>2. <span><b>второй</b> элемент списка</span></span>
  Последняя строка
  </td></tr></table>";
var js = @" document.querySelector('p').removeNode();
            var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
            for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) { spans[i].removeNode(); }
            document.querySelector('tbody').removeNode();
            document.querySelector('table').removeNode(); ";
var t = Html.CleanupAsync(html, js);
Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
```

Comment: если надо обработать много html-файлов, то код надо переписать так чтобы WebBrowser создавался один раз, а не для каждого файла.
p.s.
объект WebBrowser создается достаточно быстро, примерно, за 10 msec.